# How to parse a column delimited with a comma?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, parsing

I have the following select query (using SQL Server 2017):

```
SELECT PAYMENT_INFO
FROM CHECK_PAYMENT
WHERE (PAYMENT_FISCAL_DATE = '01/19/2018')
  AND (TENDER_MEDIA_NAME LIKE 'PaymentCard%')
ORDER BY VOID, TENDER_MEDIA_NAME
```

The output is a very long semicolon delimited string that I want to just return the first two fields.

Current output:

```
AmericanExpress;XXXXXXXXXXX4111;;;;41.47;8.00...............
MasterCard;XXXXXXXXXXXX7971;;;;40.22;10.00................
Visa;XXXXXXXXXXXX6302;;;;11.94;0.00....................
```

Desired output:

```
AmericanExpress;XXXXXXXXXXX4111
MasterCard;XXXXXXXXXXXX7111
Visa;XXXXXXXXXXXX6111
```

If possible I would like these separated into two columns.

I have looked through stack and found similar questions but have not found an answer that works or that I can figure out how to modify for my situation.

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2017 engine.

Comment: Look at [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) and consider using a subquery from it as one of the fields of the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the below function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ColumnSplitter
(
  @String VARCHAR(MAX),
  @NroSubString INT,
  @Separator VARCHAR(5)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @St INT = 0, @End INT = 0, @Ret VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @String = @String + @Separator
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Separator, @String, @End + 1) > 0 AND @NroSubString > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @St = @End + 1
        SET @End = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @String, @End + 1)
        SET @NroSubString = @NroSubString - 1
    END
    IF @NroSubString > 0
        SET @Ret = ''
    ELSE
        SET @Ret = SUBSTRING(@String, @St, @End - @St)
    RETURN @Ret
END
GO
```

Then use it in your query.

```
SELECT dbo.ColumnSplitter(PAYMENT_INFO, 1, ';') as FirstColumn,
       dbo.ColumnSplitter(PAYMENT_INFO, 2, ';') as SecondColumn      
FROM CHECK_PAYMENT
WHERE (PAYMENT_FISCAL_DATE = '01/19/2018')
  AND (TENDER_MEDIA_NAME LIKE 'PaymentCard%')
```

Comment: I get the following error: SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.

Comment: Did you get the error while creating the function or running the query?

Comment: running the query,  I put the function at the top of the query.  Does the function go inside the query I am building?

Comment: No, you should run the create function first. It will then be available in Programmability -> Functions -> Scalar-Valued Functions. Then you can run the query without any issues.

Comment: If I just run the function by it self, I get that error.

Comment: OK, I see what I was doing wrong.  function and query is giving me what I need.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a single column with the values separated with a semicolon:

```
declare @example as table (
    exampleid int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   value_ nvarchar(255) not null
);

insert into @example (value_)

select 'AmericanExpress;XXXXXXXXXXX4111;;;;41.47;8.00...............' union all
select 'MasterCard;XXXXXXXXXXXX7971;;;;40.22;10.00................' union all
select 'Visa;XXXXXXXXXXXX6302;;;;11.94;0.00....................'

select substring(value_, 0, charindex(';', value_, charindex(';', value_) + 1)) Payment_Info
  from @example
```

Comment: Sorry this is not helpful.  I would like to use the semicolon to divide the first two fields

Comment: So payment_info appears to be giant string with semicolons contained in it or you've not given us enough information. By using the substring function it will still have your semicolon in it.

Comment: Well, there are several different card types so the length of the string will be different.  I have updated my question to show the different card types that need to get pulled out.

Comment: So then you either want two columns or you want it separated by a semicolon, which is it?

Comment: you should be able to open a new query window and run that code, it is a full example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        LEFT(PAYMENT_INFO, 
                   CHARINDEX(';', PAYMENT_INFO, 
                             CHARINDEX(';', PAYMENT_INFO) + 1))
FROM          CHECK_PAYMENT
WHERE        (PAYMENT_FISCAL_DATE = '01/19/2018')
     AND (TENDER_MEDIA_NAME LIKE 'PaymentCard%')
ORDER BY VOID, TENDER_MEDIA_NAME
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error in list of function arguments: 'FROM' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: 'AND' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text

Comment: @joey.coyle missing )